# Using sysdate in Cognos Report

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, sysdate

My cognos report uses sysdate-n to retrieve records for a specified date. The report execution time varies. Suppose my report runs into the next day i.e past 12:00 am would that mess up records received or do the records retrieved depend only on the time the report was executed?

Comment: Is the value of sysdate set during run time or prior to execution?

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult question to answer without seeing how complex the Cognos generated SQL in the report is.

As Sana comment implies, generally the SQL will be executed and the value of sysdate is set during the first hit, however we have seen some very odd logs in the database when there are complex reports where different sections of SQL are executed for different filters - this would mean that when those snippets of SQL run then it *might* cause problems for you.

If you can post the sql of the report that would help, but probably the best option is to test it out - run the report at 11:55pm and see how the results differ to when run at 12:01am